# Django: How to dynamically store user data in sessions?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-allauth, django-sessions

I am trying to create different django-allauth signup forms for different types of users. So different forms for different user types. Once a user selects a user type (example: "I want to sign up as a vendor"), they should be redirected to a different form where they will complete other signup and profile details before email confirmation and login. I have one django-allauth signup form working, but not multiple. Currently I have a general purpose signup form assigned to users/accounts/signup/ but I also want a vendor specific signup form assigned to users/accounts/signup_vendor/. I have tried everything I can think of.

The best possible solution I've found, while not ideal, is provided by the django-allauth author, stating:

> "There are multiple ways to approach this. You could store the desired
> user type into the session, and dynamically construct your form fields
> depending on that. Or, you could allow for the user to make up his
> mind at any time by simply adding a "profile type" to the sign up
> form. Basically, the fields in the signup form would have to be the
> union of all possible fields, and perhaps you would want to add some
> Javascript to dynamically show/hide some fields depending on the type
> chosen. I would recommend an approach where the user can make up his
> mind about the profile type at any stage." [link to thread](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/535)

I am new to django, and new to web app dev. How can I best store user type data into sessions, and then dynamically construct form fields depending on that?

Currently, this is what I have:
`settings.py`

```
#assign to custom form
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'users.forms.GeneralSignupForm'
```

`users.models.py`

```
    class User(AbstractUser):
        class UserTypes(models.TextChoices):
            ....
        ....
    class VendorUser(models.Model):
        userinfo = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`users.forms.py`

```
class GeneralSignupForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Your first name")
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=150, help_text="Your last name")
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=150)

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.phone = self.cleaned_data['phone']
        user.save()
```

`users.views.py`

```
class GeneralSignupView(SignupView):
    template_name = 'account/signup.html'
    form_class = GeneralSignupForm
    redirect_field_name = 'next'
    view_name = 'signup'
    success_url = None

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(GeneralSignupView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data.update(self.kwargs)
        return data
```

`users.urls.py`

```
path('accounts/signup/', views.GeneralSignupView.as_view(), name='signup'),
```

`urls.py`

```
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

Answer (score 0):

what about creating a model and linking it to user model with ForeignKey? for instance, you can name your model 'type', than use it with user.type

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I already have that model structure actually (I forgot to include that in my description). My issue is how best to dynamically render a form specific to user.type within the constraints of django-allauth.